# Remove duplication row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have four column, `facilities_id`, `name`, `date` and `quantity` for my `gridview`. My problem is it have same `facilities_id` in my result. So how can i settle it, anyone can help me? Thanks..

In additional, i hope can find the top 2 row in gridview. Mean just show up the top 2 row..
Thanks

```
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();


    var query = from p in db.Facilities
                join v in db.Reservations on p.facilities_id equals v.facilities_id
                join c in db.Reservation_Details on v.reservation_id equals 
                c.resevation_id

                where SqlMethods.Like(c.date, "%" + DropDownList1.Text + "%")
                select new
                {
                    p.facilities_id,
                    p.name,
                    c.date,
                    Quantity = p.Reservations.Count()

                };

    GridView1.DataSource = query;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Here is my output, how to remove the same facilities_id.

```
facilities_id  name    date        quantity
  F001           aa    12/01/2014      1
  F001           aa    12/01/2014      12
  F002           bb    12/01/2014      1
  F003           cc    12/01/2014      1
```

i hope can become like this.

```
facilities_id  name    date        quantity
  F001           aa    12/01/2014      13
  F002           bb    12/01/2014      1
  F003           cc    12/01/2014      1
```

Comment: try using `Distinct()` with `facilities_id`

Comment: Suppose you need to group your output by `facilities_id`.

Comment: You can use distinct extension method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . you can also group by extension method http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Well, if you want that, the quantity seems to be irrelevant, so why display it? If you need the quantity, too, the double entry seems legit. You could group and sum up the quantity.

Comment: Why you use `SqlMethods.Like` for filtering date? Is `c.date` of type `datetime` in you your DB?

Comment: i not using datetime, i use varchar

Comment: @user3428639 Using `varchar` instead of `Date/DateTime` for dates is something you should really spend a second thought on...

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource = query.DistinctBy( i => i.facilities_id);
```

or

You can use GroupBy() and select the first item of each group to achieve what you want - assuming you want to pick one item for each distinct facilities_idproperty:

```
  GridView1.DataSource  = query.GroupBy(x => x.facilities_id)
                         .Select(g => g.First())
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain why you use `.Select(g => g.First())`?

Comment: To take the first distinct element from the grouped distinct list

Comment: I know what it takes. Where is the meaning?

Comment: Meaning? what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for unique facilities_id.
I dont know that you are getting data from dataset or table.

I have return a code which is retrieving the code in dataset and that dataset going to be unique.

And also your quantity will be added but facilities_id will not be repeated.

```
     var sells = from row in ds.Tables["cartTable"].AsEnumerable() ("Write here your table name as I dont know your table name ")
                    group row by row.Field<string>("facilities_id") into rowGroup
                    select new
                    {
                        facilities_id = rowGroup.Key,

                        name = string.Join(" ", rowGroup.Select(row => row.Field<string>("name")).Distinct().ToArray()),

                        date = string.Join(" ", rowGroup.Select(row => row.Field<string>("date")).Distinct().ToArray()),

                        price = string.Join(" ", rowGroup.Select(row => row.Field<decimal>("price")).Distinct().ToArray()),

                        Quantity = rowGroup.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("quantity")),

                    };


I hope this code will be useful to you......!!!!
```