# Remove Duplicates in Gridview: INNER JOIN SQL

Tags: sql, gridview, oracle10g, distinct

I have an INNER JOIN database call to fill a table based on the last login value.

SQL is like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE table2.lastlog >= '20151124%' 
ORDER BY table1.companyName
```

The issue is, when the inner join looks at table2, I have multiple times when the user logged in based on query.

So when my gridview is filled it shows all of them. I just want to show the user once if they meet the requirement.

Therefore, I tried to use the reference http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?684370-Datagridview-Remove-Duplicates

like so:

```
 For Loop1 As Integer = 0 To DisplaySup.Rows.Count - 2
    For Loop2 As Integer = Loop1 + 1 To DisplaySup.Rows.Count - 2
        If DisplaySup.Rows(Loop1).Cells(2).Text = DisplaySup.Rows(Loop2).Cells(2).Text Then
            DisplaySup.Rows.RemoveAt(Loop2)
        End If
    Next
 Next
```

However, the line `RemoveAt` gives an error: `Error 325 'RemoveAt' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection'.`

I have also tried to reference [Remove duplication row in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454013/remove-duplication-row-in-gridview) like so:

```
DisplaySup.DataSource = Query.GroupBy(x >= x.companyName).[Select](g >= g.First()).ToList()
```

OR

```
DisplaySup.DataSource = Query.DistinctBy(Function(i) i.companyName)
```

but I don't see where the `x` and `g` are declared plus I get a flag error that `DistinctBy` and `GroupBy` are not a member of Query.

Any suggestions?

I have thought about adding `DISTINCT` to my sql but I am unsure how to when I `select *` and within there `companyName` must be `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove duplicates, my quick workaround is to simply hide them.

Might not be the best option since an SQL DISTINCT use would be more proficient; however, how my SQL queries makes it difficult to do so.

Therefore I did the following:

```
Dim oldvalue As String
oldvalue = String.Empty
   If DisplaySup.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            oldvalue = DisplaySup.Rows(0).Cells(2).Text

            For i = 1 To DisplaySup.Rows.Count - 1

                Dim currentV As String = DisplaySup.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text

                If (oldvalue = currentV) Then
                    DisplaySup.Rows(i).Visible = False
                Else
                    oldvalue = DisplaySup.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text
                End If
           Next

  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't do it in your query? Something like this :

```
SELECT * from table1 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) * FROM table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
ORDER BY lastlog DESC
) AS T2
```

And you you select whatever you want from T2

Comment: I haven't seen `Cross Apply` before but from what I understand... SELECT TOP(1) would pull my first column in table2 even though I need the DISTINCT column to be from table1. Which is my issue since I need to select all from table 1. Am I correct in how I am reading your code?

Comment: Also the last login value is populated from a textbox that the user chooses. Which is why you see it

Comment: Can you put your tables structure?

Comment: Table1 has 72 columns and Table2 has 5 columns of information. Table1 and Table2 share the same ID; however Table2 list the last login value and Table1 provides the Company Name. Also the gridview displays Table2's information only.